# How to fix this web scraping program?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im a complete beginner with python, and I wrote this program to scrape and find closing odds of NHL games off The Score website, and put that data in a file. The program runs but for some reason only 2 games out of the about 200 I tried show up with incorrect data.

I think it is because of how I am search through divs within a div, I wrote the code that returns the data from that in a way that it only stores that last div (which conveniently is the div im looking to scrape).

Also im sure my way of writing to the file is poor for runtime, is there a better way to do this?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Function to scrape web and find the game title and closing odds
def get_match_data(url_val):
    # Set up html parser
    response = requests.get(url_val)
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    # Scrape for header which is "matchtitle"
    matchtitle = soup.find('h1',{'class': "sr-only"})
   
    # Code to find div and search for div within
    divs = soup.find('div',{'class': 'col-sm-4'})
    for tag in divs:
        # find div
        target = tag.find_all("div", {"class","GameDetailsCard__row--3rKYp"})
        for tag in target:
            # find divs within target div
            odds = tag.find("div", {"class","GameDetailsCard__content--2L_KF"})
    # Call write_to_file -> add data scraped from web
    write_to_file(matchtitle.text +" "+ odds.text)

# Code to pass multiple urls to scrape for different games
def multi_games_url_handler(link):
    for x in range(26500, 26715):
        #print(x)
        url = link + str(x)
        #print(url)
        get_match_data(url)
        
def write_to_file(game_data):
    file = open("NHL_GAMES.txt","a")
    file.write(game_data +"\n")
    file.close


### Main(void) ?? idk what to call this portion of code not a python savant
# Fetch the webpage
link = "https://www.thescore.com/nhl/events/"
multi_games_url_handler(link)
```

Here is one line in the text file with correct data:

Toronto Maple Leafs @ New Jersey Devils on November 24, 2022 NJD -140, o/u 6.5

Here is one with incorrect data

Carolina Hurricanes @ Anaheim Ducks on December 7, 2022 Justin St. Pierre, Chris Lee

Only 2/215 were wrong like this.

Comment: In python executing the main function is either done as you did, by just running functions at the top level, or with an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. Also in `write_to_file` your file handle is not closed as you aren't calling `file.close()`, you should look into using a `with open() as file:` block.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that certain NHL game webpages ex: Carolina does not contain a <div> section for the 'Odds', this might be due to then being OT games? Regardless best bet is to add in a clause to handle 'no odds found'. I have updated some of your code below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Function to scrape web and find the game title and closing odds
def get_match_data(url_val):
    results = []
    # Set up html parser
    response = requests.get(url_val)
    html = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    
    # Scrape for header which is "matchtitle"
    matchtitle = soup.find('h1',{'class': "sr-only"})
    target = soup.find_all("div", {"class","GameDetailsCard__row--3rKYp"})
    
    for tag in target:
        if "Odds" in str(tag.find("div", {"class":"GameDetailsCard__label--iBMhJ"})):
            odds = str(tag.find("div", {"class":"GameDetailsCard__content--2L_KF"}).text)
        else:
            odds = "No Odds found!"
        
    print(matchtitle.text + " " + odds)
    results.append(matchtitle.text + " " + odds)
    # Call write_to_file -> add data scraped from web
    write_to_file(results)
    
# Code to pass multiple urls to scrape for different games
def multi_games_url_handler(link):
    print("Getting game details...")
    for x in range(26500, 26715):
        #print(x)
        url = link + str(x)
        #print(url)
        get_match_data(url)
    
def write_to_file(game_data):
    with open("NHL_GAMES.txt", "a") as file:
        for line in game_data:
            file.write(line + "\n")


### Main(void) ?? idk what to call this portion of code not a python savant
# Fetch the webpage
link = "https://www.thescore.com/nhl/events/"
multi_games_url_handler(link)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! had some more time to work on my code and learn a bit more python. When I tried your method of "write_to_file" it wrote the data to the text file one character per line, it was an easy fix but it confused me a bit...
When I looped through the collection of "divs" object python handled one div at a time 'for tag in target' but when you looped through a string 'for line in gameData' it handled one character at a time?

Comment: Its printing each character out one at a time because you are passing in a string as a variable to the function. The for loop will traverse the length of the string printing out each value it grabs, in this case the char's in the string. In my example I saved the string data I pulled out of the divs into an array and passed the array into the write_file_function to allow for only a single instance of opening and writing to a file instead of doing it multiple times for every single string you would pass to it.